# Downloading files throwing Network Failure from webapps hosted on kubernetes using tomcat

Tags: kubernetes, tomcat

A very strange issue is noticed during downloading files in 2 webapps running as pods hosted in our on-premise kubernetes cluster using tomcat9 image and openjdk8.
Though both application functionalities are different but the issue is similar and related to downloading files i will describe about the issue as follows.

1. We have mounted an NFS share across all the machines in the cluster and the mount point is given in the yaml file as a volume which in turn is mounted inside the pod
2. The application lists these files with a download button
3. Small files are getting downloaded without any issues. But when we click on large files maybe above say 75mb the files download successfully sometimes or slow down suddenly but eventually download or fail with "Network Error". This is happening consistently across all browsers
   4.NFS server(ZFS) and the cluster machines(CentOS) are within same subnet and no firewall is present in between.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logreaderkube-deployment
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: tomcat
    name: logreaderkube
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: logreaderkube
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: logreaderkube
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logreaderkube
        image: gg.gg.gg.gg:5000/logreader:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        securityContext:
         allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - name: tz-config
            mountPath: /etc/localtime
          - name: log-volume
            mountPath: /opt/logs/
        volumes:
        - name: tz-config
          hostPath:
              path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta
        - name: log-volume
          hostPath:
              path: /mnt/logs
              
              

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logreaderkube-service
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: logreaderkube
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30030



apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: logreaderkube-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kube-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "logreaderkube"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "gg.gg.gg.gg"
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: logreaderkube-service
            servicePort: 80
```

As the application doesn't have any login, I tried downloading using curl with pod ip address inside a cluster machine to eliminate ingress role. Even then behaviour is same either slow download, or network error or downloads succesfully sometimes but the behaviour is inconsistent.

I tried downloading by copying large files from the NFS to a local folder and launched the Pod from the server with local folder.Even then download functionality is inconsistent

This application when hosted on a standalone tomcat(windows) with oracle jdk8 with the same NFS mount works for downloads consistently.

The other application(built using struts2) uses cifs mount points for volume mounts.CIFS machines and cluster machines are within same subnet and no firewall is present between them.

The above steps are performed except the curl step as this app has login. But the problem with downloads is same. I hosted this application similarly in a standalone tomcat(windows) with symbolic links for file location. The download functionality works perfectly fine.

The erratic behavior on Kubernetes for both applications is consistent across timeframes either with less or more traffice

The only similiarity that I found between these applications is using streams for downloading files

Code Snippet from first application is below

```
else if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
                response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + f.getName()
                        + "\"");
                response.setContentLength((int) f.length());
                BufferedInputStream fileInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                byte buffer[] = new byte[8 * 1024];
                out.clearBuffer();
                OutputStream out_s = new Writer2Stream(out);
                copyStreamsWithoutClose(fileInput, out_s, buffer);
                fileInput.close();
                out_s.flush();
```

Kubernetes version is 1.18.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE: I have run both applications in native docker containers and didn't face any issues with downloading files from with in application. So I think this is an issue only through Kubernetes pods. Any pointers on how to debug is helpful.

Comment: How did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: It's a bare metal installation .